# CVS update in crontab

Tags: cron, cvs

I've made a sh script for update my work directory every night:

```
20 20 * * * /home/oracle/scripts/lancia_script.ksh /home/oracle/setORACLE_ENV   /home/oracle/scripts/update_cvs.ksh > /home/oracle/logs/crontab/update_cvs.log 2>&1
```

file update_cvs.ksh:

```
[...]
cd $CVSDIR
cvs update
cd -
cp -R $CVSDIR/* $SCRIPTSDIR/
chmod 744 $SCRIPTSDIR/*.ksh
[...]
```

If I run it manually there aren't problems, but if I schedule it I recived:

```
cvs [update aborted]: cannot exec rsh: No such file or directory 
cvs [update aborted]: end of file from server (consult above messages if any) /u01/home/oracle
```

Why?

Comment: You've already worked out the answer to your specific problem but it's worth noting for the future that cron jobs do not run with the same environment variables as you when you are at an interactive shell. That's typically the cause of most "Fine when I run it manually but not via cron" problems.

Answer (score 2):

At first I suspected that CVS run from crontab couldn't find `rsh` due to difference in `PATH` variable in login shell and in `cron` environment.

I was wrong, the answer is to set `CVS_RSH` to `ssh` in script run from crontab, as original author figured out. This is because CVS being really old defaults to `rsh` as remote shell. But as `rsh` isn't secure, probably most administrators of CVS repositories require connection with a secure shell, `ssh`.

Credit goes to: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/12636#comment42630

Comment: /usr/bin/which: no rsh in (/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/ucb:/etc:.:/usr/openwin/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/sfw/bin:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin:/home/oracle/scripts)

Comment: What you get when you type `echo $CVS_RSH`?

Comment: If i run it from crontab CVS_RSH is unset. If I run in console CVS_RSH=ssh.

Answer (score 1):

I write

```
[...]
export CVS_RSH=ssh
cd $CVSDIR
cvs update
cd -
cp -R $CVSDIR/* $SCRIPTSDIR/
chmod 744 $SCRIPTSDIR/*.ksh
[...]
```

It works!